# What is details meaning of output and input Impedance?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I was studying the CC, CB and CE Amplifier. And I have found a sentence somewhere that,

"Maximum power transfer occurs when load impedance is equal to source impedance."

As much as I understand impedance is something that opposes current. But, what are this load impedance, output impedance, input impedance? I mean how are the related to. 
In the case of CC, CE, CB amplifiers, how are they related to each other and what are the meaning in this case?

Thanks in Advanced. Hope somebody will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give a mathematical definition, if we were to excite the input of a two-port with a sinusoidal current source

$$i_{in}(t) = I_0 + I \sin(\omega t)$$

with \$I\$ small enough to not cause any nonlinear behavior, we'd find

$$v_{in}(t) = V_0 + V_i \sin(\omega t) + V_q \cos(\omega t)$$

Then we could define

$$R_{in} = \frac{V_i}{I}$$

and

$$X_{in} = \frac{V_q}{I}.$$

Then the input impedance would be \$Z_{in}\$ if we defined

$$Z_{in} = R_{in} + j X_{in}.$$

In words, this means that the real part of \$Z_{in}\$ tells us how the in-phase component of the input voltage depends on the input current. And the imaginary part of \$Z_{in}\$ tells us how the quadrature (90 degree phase shifted) part of the input voltage depends on the input current.

We would also find that

$$R_{in} = \frac{{\rm{d}}V_0}{{\rm{d}}I_0}.$$

The output impedance is defined the same way, but as a relationship between the output current and output voltage.

All the other things we know about input and output impedance and how they relate to circuit behavior can be connected back to these definitions.

> "Maximum power transfer occurs when load impedance is equal to source impedance."

This isn't quite correct.

First, when talking about possibly complex-valued impedances, maximum power transfer occurs when the source impedance is the complex conjugate of the load impedance.

Second, this maximum power transfer condition is for choosing the load impedance when the source impedance is fixed. If source impedance can be controlled, then either very high impedance (with a fixed-current source) or very low impedance (for a fixed-voltage source) should be chosen to deliver maximum power to a fixed impedance load.

Comment: @Allen, I realized my initial answer was very sloppy, so I did a near complete re-write after you accepted. Hopefully it's still clear enough.

Comment: it was a great answer. I highly appreciate the mathematical explanation you have made for me. I am a student of Theoretical Physics, and this maths helped me a lot to understand the insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Input impedance is the impedance that is "seen" by a device when connecting to a circuit's input. For example if I connect a source to the input of any of the amplifiers you just mentioned, the input impedance would be Vin/Iin

The output impedance on the other hand is the impedance seen when looking into the circuit from the output.

And the load impedance is simply the impedance of the load itself that you attach to the output.

It's also important to note the impedance is actually a complex value that includes the magnitude and phase shift that will result at a given frequency.

As for the line you quoted.. it can be mathematically proven that Power is maximized when Rs = RL... Take for example a simple circuit with source with Rs and RL in series.

VL = Vs*RL/(RL+Rs)

PL = VL^2/RL

if we differentiate PL with respect to RL we can prove that:

d(PL)/d(RL) = 0 
When RL = Rs

Therefore showing that the maximum value of PL occurs at RL = Rs

But another thing you should realize is that the quote you posted isn't entirely correct. In fact it's wrong... **The power is maximized when source impedance equals the conjugate of the load impedance**..

The key word is **conjugate**

This is because impedance as I stated before is a complex value that represents magnitude and phase shift. The phase shift (imaginary part) serves to place the voltage and current out of phase and therefore reduce power.... If the source and load impedance are conjugates:

Zs = R + jX

&

ZL = R - jX

Then the imaginary parts (phase shift) will cancel and you will be back at the derivation I defined previously

Comment: NP man. Keep up the good fight!

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that maximum power transfer is a 6dB loss of voltage. Thus broadband amplifier design does not use matched interfaces.

I trained a team of highly motivated RFIC designers. They were concerned about onchip transfer of signal between "stages". I explained "At these distances (100 microns), we are implementing broad-band operational amplifiers that happen to amplify 250MHz sinusoids. There is no matching possible nor needed."

Comment: Good example! Honestly, the first thing I think of when I see 250MHz is impedance matching everything... Guess it's drilled into the brain a little much haha

Comment: We had lotta fun. Such as Noise Voltage or Noise Figure. Turns out the radio industry was having that very same debate at their conferences, as they for the first time needed to convert from PCBs (and those tiny silver metal cans with 50 ohm in/out) to silicon.